# Design O(log n) algorithm for finding 3 distinct elements in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

The question is:

> Design an O(log n) algorithm whose input is a sorted list A. The algorithm should return true if A contains at least 3 distinct elements. Otherwise, the algorithm should return false.

as it has to be O(log n), I tried to use binary search and this is the code I wrote:

```
def hasThreeDistinctElements(A):
    if len(A) < 3:
        return False
    minInd = 0
    maxInd = len(A)-1
    midInd = (maxInd+minInd)//2
    count = 1
    while minInd < maxInd: 
        if A[minInd] == A[midInd]:
            minInd = midInd
            if A[maxInd] == A[midInd]:
                maxInd = midInd
            else:
                count += 1
                maxInd -= 1
        else:
            count += 1
            minInd += 1
        midInd = (maxInd+minInd)//2
  
    return count >= 3
```

is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: "it returns the correct answer " - no, it doesn't. `hasThreeDistinctElements([0,0,0, 0, 1, 1, 1])` returns `True`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille good catch :)

Comment: Is it acceptable to be better than O(logN)?

Comment: You can easily do it by using `len(set(A)) ` but the question wants O(log N) algorithm

Comment: @Morez that would be O(N), I think abhinavmathur is asking if O(1) is also allowed, though I'm fairly sure this is impossible.

Comment: @ADdV I can't think of a constant time approach for this problem!

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Everything better than O(logN) is also O(logN), so yes, of course. So please share that.

Comment: @KellyBundy I had an idea, but realized it wasn't a concrete algorithm and would fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to really be `O(logN)`, the updates to the bounding indeces `minInd,maxInd` should only ever be

```
maxInd = midInd [- 1]
minInd = midInd [+ 1]
```

to half the search space. Since there are paths through your loop body that only do

```
minInd += 1
maxInd -= 1
```

respectively, I am not sure that you can't create data for which your function is linear. The following is a bit simpler and guaranteed `O(logN)`

```
def x(A):
    if len(A) < 3:
        return False
    minInd, maxInd = 0, len(A)-1
    mn, mx = A[minInd], A[maxInd]

    while minInd < maxInd:
        midInd = (minInd + maxInd) // 2
        if mn != A[midInd] != mx:
            return True
        if A[midInd] == mn:
            minInd = midInd + 1  # minInd == midInd might occur 
        else:
            maxInd = midInd  # while maxInd != midInd is safe

    return False
```

BTW, if you can use the standard library, it is as easy as:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def x(A):
    return A and (i := bisect_right(A, A[0])) < len(A) and A[i] < A[-1]
```

Comment: I tested your function with this example `[1,2,4,4,4]` and it returns false.

Comment: Ah yes, the update of `maxInd` was one too generous. Amended.

Comment: Crash when A is empty. And you don't need to check `A[0] < A[i]`.

Comment: Hmm, if it's empty, then your somewhat short one now returns `[]`. It shall "return false". Unclear what that means, so maybe `[]` is ok. (I say "somewhat short" because mine's shorter :-P)

Comment: True, that was a quickfix... at least it's falsy :-)

Comment: Oh come on!!!!111! Why say "falsy" when the word "false" is already in play... aaaaaaaaaaaargh. That's one of my biggest pet peeves. The Python documentation/reference says true/false, never truthy/falsy, and it soooooo annoys me when people use the latter. And in this case, we could argue that in Python, "return a false value" is a legitimate intepretation of "return false". Gets less convincing if you say "falsy" instead.

Comment: Ah, I see you have triggers, too :D I for one, like the distinction these terms provide. Even PEPs [authored by Guido himself](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) use the terms.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have too many triggers :-). Bah, that's somewhat disappointing. But at least he put them in quotes there, in my mind indicating that he knows those are not the proper terms. But they don't appear to be anywhere [on docs.python.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org+"truthy"+OR+"falsy") (other than in the changelog because two people wrote "falsy" in a changeset). And yeah, maybe the distinction helps, maybe truthy/falsy is clearer to more people, but if everybody used true/false, that might be equally clear. I mean, if the docs do it, it's probably clear enough?

Answer (score 5):

```
from bisect import bisect

def hasThreeDistinctElements(A):
    return A[:1] < A[-1:] > [A[bisect(A, A[0])]]
```

The first comparison safely<sup>(*)</sup> checks whether there are two different values at all. If so, we check whether the first value larger than `A[0]` is also smaller than `A[-1]`.

(*): Doesn't crash if `A` is empty.

Or without `bisect`, binary-searching for a third value in `A[1:-1]`. The invariant is that if there is any, it must be in `A[lo : hi+1]`:

```
def hasThreeDistinctElements(A):
    lo, hi = 1, len(A) - 2
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if A[mid] == A[0]:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif A[mid] == A[-1]:
            hi = mid - 1
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Even cleverer usage of `bisect`!

Comment: Very clever indeed! ”Ungolfing“ the double inequality would require to write `len(A) > 2 and A[0] < A[-1] and A[bisect(A, A[0])] < A[-1]` (the second condition prevents an error on `[x, x, ..., x]`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better approach.

As the list is sorted, you can use binary search with slight custom modifications as follows:

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]

uniqueElementSet = set([])

def binary_search(minIndex, maxIndex, n):
    
    if(len(uniqueElementSet)>=3):
        return
        
    #Checking the bounds for index:
    if(minIndex<0 or minIndex>=n or maxIndex<0 or maxIndex>=n):
        return
    
    if(minIndex > maxIndex):
        return
    
    if(minIndex == maxIndex):
        uniqueElementSet.add(list[minIndex])    
        return
    
    if(list[minIndex] == list[maxIndex]):
        uniqueElementSet.add(list[minIndex])    
        return
    
    uniqueElementSet.add(list[minIndex])
    uniqueElementSet.add(list[maxIndex])
    
    midIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex)//2
    
    binary_search(minIndex+1, midIndex, n)
    
    binary_search(midIndex+1, maxIndex-1, n)
    
    return

binary_search(0, len(list)-1, len(list))

print(True if len(uniqueElementSet)>=3 else False)
```

As, we are dividing the array into 2 parts in each iteration of the recursion, it will require maximum of log(n) steps to check if it contains 3 unique elements.

**Time Complexity = O(log(n)).**